# Change Hangfire table names in OnModelCreating

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, hangfire

My web app is in asp.net MVC with mysql database.

Here is the hangfire configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHangfire(configuration => {
        configuration.UseStorage(
            new MySqlStorage(
                "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=root;database={0};Allow User Variables=True",
                new MySqlStorageOptions
                {
                    TablesPrefix = "Hangfire"
                }
            )
        );
    };
}
```

I'm getting excepton table `hangfireSet` not found. In database table is created as `hangfireset`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>().ToTable("tablename");
    }
```

How can I access hangfire model classes in OnModelCreating so that I can change table names to lower case.

Answer (score 5):

Since `Hangfire` is not part of your ContextDb, then you could NOT change its tables name in this way. Instead, you can achieve this in `Hangfire` configuration.

```
    services.AddHangfire(cfg => cfg
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseSqlServerStorage("YOURCONNECTIONSTRING",
            new Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                /* other configs */
                SchemaName = "Your own scheme"
            }));
```